# Drupal 8 unable to get path location from custom module

Tags: drupal-8

I created a **module** in Drupal 8 that needs to **load a csv file** from the module folder, but I was unable to do it, I have already tried:

```
$directory = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
$file = 'source.csv';
$path = $directory . '/' . $file;
kint($path);

// open the CVS file
$handle = fopen($path, 'r');
if (!$handle) {
  // ...
}
```

But I'm getting `false` when loading the file, so looks like it's not the correct way.

Comment: What is the return value of `drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');` ? Are you sure the file is located into `my_modules/source.csv` ? And finally, where do you execute this code: into a Block Plugin, Controller, Service, my_module.module ? With all this informations I may help you, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to got it using the following code:

```
$file = 'source.csv';
$path = __DIR__ . '/' . $file;
// open the CVS file
$handle = @fopen($path, 'r');
if (!$handle) {
  // ...
}
```

If there is a better way just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

basically:

```
$moduleDir = drupal_get_path('module','my_module');
```

is the right way

so if your source.csv file is located under **modules/MY_MODULE/files/sources.csv**

then you should be able to do something like the following in your my_module.module file or elsewhere:

```
$file = $moduleDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sources.csv;
if(file_exists($file)){
  //do your stuff
}
```